# How to extract/split numbers and string out from NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a NSString *text = @"randomtext12345"

The text string will always begins with 'string' (unknown length) and followed by 'number' (integer type).

There is no 'seperator' in between the text, how do I detect which is string and integer? in order to extract/seperate/seperate out the text to become

```
NSString *key = @"randomtext";
NSInteger value = 12345;
```

Comment: I think you are using `NSInteger` wrong. And is your input always in the same format? Is `key` always a string? or can it contain numbers?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII ya, the 'key' is always a string

Answer (score 5):

This assumes that all numeric values are grouped together at the end (i.e. there are no numbers in the "randomtext" portion).  Also, I have not included error checking to make sure that the input string (`text`) is in the correct format.  (i.e. there must be an alpha portion followed by a numeric portion):

```
NSString *text = @"randomtext12345";

NSRange beginningOfNumber = [text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
if (beginningOfNumber.location == NSNotFound)
{
    return;
}

NSString *key           = [text substringToIndex:beginningOfNumber.location];
NSString *stringValue   = [text substringFromIndex:beginningOfNumber.location];
NSInteger value         = [stringValue integerValue];

// Output:  2012-07-29 14:08:56.504 Testing App[46439:fb03] key: randomtext, value: 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a separator string between the string and number.
"~" in this example.
NSInteger is not an object, so don't use the "*".

```
NSString *test = @"randomtext~12345";
NSArray *testItems = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];

NSString *key = [testItems objectAtIndex:0];
NSInteger value = [[testItems objectAtIndex:1] intValue];

NSLog(@"test key=%@ and value=%ld", key, value);
```

Comment: at the moment there is not 'seperator' in between the text

Comment: Do you know the exact length of the text or numeric portion of the test string?

Comment: it supposed to be random, but in my case, the character length can varying from 1-3, numeric value range from 0-999. Meaning the Min. text length is 2 (example: a1), Max. text length will be 6 (example: abc999)